# Sphinx return empty result on cyrillic query

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, sphinx

Still normal search with latin and russian translit(!)

```
$ search sumka   
using config file '/etc/sphinx/sphinx.conf'...
index 'test1': query 'sumka ': returned 636 matches of 636 total in 0.000 sec

displaying matches:
1. document=154143, weight=1660, name=Сумка Sony LCS-MS10 Gray Alpha Текстильная сумка для фотокамеры Alpha Серый цвет, casual style (сумка почтальона) [LCSMS10H.AE], description_short=Сумка Sony LCS-MS10 Gray Alpha Текстильная сумка для фотокамеры Alpha Серый цвет, casual style (сумка почтальона) [LCSMS10H.AE]
                                     ...

$ search сумка

using config file '/etc/sphinx/sphinx.conf'...
index 'test1': query 'сумка ': returned 0 matches of 0 total in 0.000 sec

words:
1. 'сумка': 0 documents, 0 hits
```

Sound like charset problem here, but I have utf8 in mysql and query

```
mysql> show variables like "character%";
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                       |
| character_set_connection | utf8                       |
| character_set_database   | utf8                       |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | utf8                       |
| character_set_server     | utf8                       |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+

mysql> show variables like "collation%";
+----------------------+-----------------+
| Variable_name        | Value           |
+----------------------+-----------------+
| collation_connection | utf8_general_ci |
| collation_database   | utf8_general_ci |
| collation_server     | utf8_unicode_ci |
+----------------------+-----------------+ 

$ file words
words: UTF-8 Unicode text
$ cat words | search --stdin 

using config file '/etc/sphinx/sphinx.conf'...
index 'test1': query 'сумка
': returned 0 matches of 0 total in 0.000 sec

words:
1. 'сумка': 0 documents, 0 hits
```

This is also true for php client and sphinx mysql like client.

Full sphinx configuration is [here](http://pastie.org/5166413), but quote of significient part:

```
source src1
{
...
sql_query_pre       = SET NAMES utf8
sql_query_pre       = SET CHARACTER SET utf8
...
}
index test1
{
...
charset_type    = utf-8
...
}
```

I found only one similar problem, but there was latin1 charset in db.

Programs versions is:

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.20, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1
Sphinx 2.0.6-id64-release (r3473)
centos 5.8
```

### UPDATE

Add charset_table to config with tables from http://sphinxsearch.com/wiki/doku.php?id=charset_tables#cyrillic but still no good.

Also I installed Sphinx 2.0.5-release (r3308) on my local gentoo and it work with cyrillic queries out of the box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And it works now.

I did not understand clearly what it was, but it work with default config and example.sql with cyrillics rows, so I dumped my DB and filled it back and it made it work. 
I think it fixed some encoding issues, that may be there after migration throw several instance of mysql.

Sorry for my pure english.:)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with the mysql interface ? ( mysql -P 9306 -h 127.0.0.1 and then do a
SELECT * FROM test1 WHERE MATCH('сумка'); )

Comment: Result is the same: 0 documents, 0 hits

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be due to the mysql encoding. Try to uncomment this line:

```
#sql_query_pre      = SET NAMES utf8
```

Default encoding for mysql can differ from utf8;